# How to add a count column to an SQL query?

Tags: sql, analytics

I am querying a table of orders for my company. I want to add a column that counts the unique "userId" for the entire table that I am querying. What does my code need to look like?

I've tried count distinct and count userId as 'num' but this isn't returning the desired results.

This isn't working:
'''SELECT
  COUNT(userId) AS 'num'
FROM [table] 
GROUP BY 
  UserId
LIMIT 1000 '''

I want the rows to look like "User Id, Total Orders" where total orders is a function of the count of UserIds all time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `GROUP BY`.  You want one of these columns:

```
SELECT COUNT(userId), COUNT(DISTINCT userId)
FROM [table];
```

Comment: Gotcha but now my count column is only returning 1. I would like to know how many instances of the userId come up throughout the entire table and have that number in the row. Currently my code looks like:
```SELECT
  userId, marketId, COUNT(DISTINCT userId)
FROM [good-uncle-bigquery-data:GoodUncleProductionDataset1.orders] 
GROUP BY
  userId, marketId```
And returns: 
```userId, marketId, 1```
Where I want: 
```userId, marketId, sumOfUserId```

Comment: @DylanGans . . . I don't see a `GROUP BY` in my answer.

Comment: If I don't use ```GROUP BY``` I receive this error, "(L2:12): (L2:46): SELECT clause has mix of aggregations 'f0_' and fields 'userId, marketId' without GROUP BY clause"

Comment: @DylanGans . . . I don't see such columns in my query.

Answer (score 0):

If you COUNT userId and GROUP BY userId you will get each unique userId and the number of times that userId has a record.

```
SELECT COUNT(userId), userId FROM table GROUP BY userId
```

See this SQL Fiddle for an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09408/786